# How can I do anything else than console.log(json) while fetching an API without getting <undefined>?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to fetch data from an api using the node fetch module.
Here's my code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Url='https://invidio.us/api/v1/search?q=the+tech+lead';

fetch(Url).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
```

When I try to do something else like storing the json into a variable then printing it out outside of the `.then(...)` I get `<undefined>`.

My question is therefore how can I manipulate and get access to the json object outside the `.then()` while not getting undefined?

Comment: Why don't you just use the json inside the `then` chain?

Comment: Do you declare the variable outside of the then() chain?